# Plugin event methods in Virtuemart for order status

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I have my order list in the backend , 
I want to fire plugin events when order status is changed from Confirmed by Shopper to "Shipped" or "Confirmed"

Already using

> plgVmConfirmedOrder()

Which is for confirmed by shopper, and successful transimission of SMS
Also

> plgVmOnShipOrderPayment() Not responding.

Any other method or way to do so?  I want this methods for the SMS gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this question.

You can use plgVmOnUpdateOrderPayment($virtuemart_order,$status) for this purpose which is fired during each order status change.

For respective order status e.g. Confirmed order-status 'C', Put a validation check as follows,

```
if($virtuemart_order->order_status != 'C')  { return ; }
```

You can use this for different order status.

Like , If the answer is useful for you.